# VBA code to apply only the last data label

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I don't speak English very well, but I hope you can understand me.

It's about a VBA code for plotting graphs. I am trying to automate my sheets and I found a simple and easy code in the internet to do so. After updating the series, my intention is to clear all data labels except for the last one.

The code is:

```
Dim oChart As ChartObject
Dim MySeries As Series

For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
 For Each MySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection

    'Clear Existing Data Labels
       MySeries.ApplyDataLabels (xlDataLabelsShowNone)
       
    'Apply Labels to Last Point
        MySeries.points(MySeries.points.Count).ApplyDataLabels
   
    Next MySeries
Next oChart

End Sub
```

But, this code runs for only three of the ten graphs, and doesn't  work for the others. I've looked for similarities or differences among the series (like the name format or type of graphic - line, bar, pie) but I could not find the problem

The first part of the macro which is delete all data labels works correctly for all the graphs, though. I also tried to do it for more than one sheet and workbook, also unsuccessfully.

Comment: how is it suppose to work on all worksheets if you are not looping through all `Worksheets` ? you need to have ` For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should over every-sheet, every chart, every series and points. `ApplyDataLabels` is a property a point not series or multiple points. `xlDataLabelsShowNone` Doesn't mean none of the points. It means that the label will not be shown in any format. You can read about this Object [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196984.aspx).

Code below would do the job for you.

```
Sub remove_label()

    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim oChart As ChartObject
    Dim MySeries As Series
    Dim oPoints As Points
    Dim MyPoint As Point
    Dim i As Long

     For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       For Each oChart In wsh.ChartObjects
         For Each MySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
           Set oPoints = MySeries.Points
             i = oPoints.Count
                For Each MyPoint In oPoints
                  i = i - 1
                    If i <> 0 Then
                     'Clear Existing Data Labels
                      MyPoint.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowNone
                    Else
                     'Apply Labels to Last Point
                      MyPoint.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowValue
                    End If

           Next MyPoint
         Next MySeries
       Next oChart
     Next wsh

End Sub
```

Comment: Really thanks, but it doesn't work yet. I am trying automate graphics first in one sheet. I changed the code according to your sugestion in a new workbook and the code runs for three of six graphs. There is graphics with two series or more. Sometime the code runs for both series of a graph, sometime only for one serie. (Sorry language mistakes).

Comment: @Ágila Check it now.